# select specific columns when using include statement with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I need a hierarchal (parent-child) relationship, I typically use the Include statement in my EF query.

Example:

```
DbContext.Customers.Include("Projects");
```

This is fine, but the Customers and Projects entities always brings back all the columns.

I know that the below query will bring back specific columns in the parent table, but I'm also trying to bring back only specific columns in the child table. If I use the intellisense on the Projects it is obviously a collection and does not give specific properties to select.

```
from c in Customers
let Projects = c.Projects.Where (p => p.Notes != null)
where Projects.Any()
select new
{
    c.UserName,
    Projects
}
```

I tried refining the query to the below code, but as you can see, the Projects entity is a **child** entity of the Customers and therefore, does not have a specific column to select in the query. It obviously is a collection.

Is there a way to bring back just **specific columns** in each of the entities when using an Include in your query?

Note that my YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers model is made up of all columns that reside in the Customer and Project entities.

```
public List<YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers> GetCustomerProjects()
        {
            try
            {
                using (YeagerTech DbContext = new YeagerTech())
                {
                    var customer = DbContext.Customers.Include("Projects").Select(s =>
                        new YeagerTechDB.ViewModels.Customers()
                        {
                            CustomerID = s.CustomerID,
                            ProjectID = s.ProjectID,
                            UserName = s.UserName,
                            Name = s.Projects.,
                        });

                     return customer.ToList();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

ANSWER #1 FOR 1 CHILD ENTITY

```
from c in Customers
let Projects = c.Projects.Where (p => p.Notes != null)
where Projects.Any()
select new
{
    c.UserName,
    Projects
}
```

ANSWER #2 FOR 2 CHILD ENTITIES

```
from c in Customers
let highValueP =
    from p in c.Projects
    where p.Quote != null
    select new { p.ProjectID, p.Name, p.Quote }
where highValueP.Any()
from p in Projects
let highValuet =
    from t in p.TimeTrackings
    where t.Notes != null
    select new { t.ProjectID, t.Notes }
where highValuet.Any()
select new 
{
    c.CustomerID,
    Projects = highValueP,
    TimeTrackings = highValuet
}
```

Edit #3
[image]

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Check this [link](http://colinmackay.scot/2011/07/31/getting-just-the-columns-you-want-from-entity-framework/) for more details. In short, the trick is to use .Select() and anonymous type to restrict the columns you want. In the example below first Select() is actually doing this:

```
var results = context.Products
        .Include("ProductSubcategory")
        .Where(p => p.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
                    && p.DiscontinuedDate == null)
        .Select(p => new
                        {
                            p.ProductID,
                            ProductSubcategoryName = p.ProductSubcategory.Name,
                            p.Name,
                            p.StandardCost
                        })
        .AsEnumerable()
        .Select(p => new AutoCompleteData
                            {
                                Id = p.ProductID,
                                Text = BuildAutoCompleteText(p.Name,
                                    p.ProductSubcategoryName, p.StandardCost)
                            })
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense... Thanks.... Can you or anyone else tell me what's wrong with EDIT #3 in my answer? Your answer and my #1 & #2 answers work fine for anonymous types, but what if I want to stick in inside a Model?

Comment: @sagesky36, a litle it late, but I think you miss the "new" key in your Select clause.

Comment: What if you're including multiple children of `Products`? E.G. If instead of `ProductSubcategory` you had `ProductSubCategories` and you want to select only the name of each of those categories.

Comment: This "works", but it causes a query per parent item instead of doing a join.

Comment: @Timoty Gonzalez how do you implement this to use join?

Comment: Do I need .AsEnumerable() inbetween?