# Excluding properties from included navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a Company class:

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public int? AnalystId { get; set; }
    public int? ReviewerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Staff Analyst { get; set; }
    public virtual Staff Reviewer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

One of the navigation properties is a CompanyFile, which looks like this:

```
public class CompanyFile
{

public int CompanyFileId { get; set; }
public Guid FileContentId { get; set; }
public int CompanyId { get; set; }
public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
public string OrigFileName { get; set; }
public byte[] FileContents { get; set; }
}
```

In the code, there's a method to load the company and its navigation properties that looks like this:

```
public async Task<Company> GetAsync(int id)
{
    return await Repo
    .Include("Analyst")
    .Include("Reviewer")
    .Include("Files")
    .Where(w => w.CompanyId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

That all works as intended, but the problem is that if the FileContents property is large, then it takes a long time to load the Company object.  Is there a way to load the CompanyFile navigation property but exclude the FileContents property?

EDIT:

- There's a link mentioned in the comments, but what the link describes is how ignore a property while creating a single object and not a collection.
- Then I tried this:

```
    return await Repo
    .Include("Analyst")
    .Include("Reviewer")
    .Include("Files")
    .Where(w => w.CompanyId == id).
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(p => new Company
    {
    p. CompanyId,
    [snip]
    Files = new File {               
        CompanyFileId = p.Files.CompanyFileId,
        FileContentId = p.Files.FileContentId,
        CompanyId = p.Files.FileContentId,
        OrigFileName = p.Files. OrigFileName 
    })
```

Compiler error: Cannot initialize type "Company" with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable

- So I tried this

  ```
   Company company = Repo
            .Include("Group")
            .Include("Analyst")
            .Include("Reviewer")
            .Include("Reviews")
            //.Include("Files")
            .Include("Priorities")
            .Where(w => w.CompanyId == id)
            .ToList()
            .FirstOrDefault();

  var FileRepo = Context.Set<CompanyFile>();
  var ReviewFiles = FileRepo.Where(f => f.CompanyId == id)
          .Select(t => new CompanyFile   {
               t.CompanyId,
               {snip]
               t.OrigFileName
                })
               .ToList();
  ```

Compile time error: Cannot initialize type CompanyFile with a collection initializer because it does not implement System.Collections.IEnumerable

- So I changed the last bit to

```
    var ReviewFiles = FileRepo.Where(f => f.CompanyId == id) 
         .Select(t => new CompanyFile { 
             CompanyId = t.CompanyId,
            [snip] 
            OrigFileName = t.OrigFileName });
```

// Run-time error: Message = "The entity or complex type 'CompanyFile' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query."

Comment: Does this work? ```.Include("Files").Ignore(f => f.FileContents)``` Found from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385248/ignoring-a-class-property-in-entity-framework-4-1-code-first

Comment: I don't think that is the right syntax. `.Ignore` is for configuring the entity itself and would remove the ability to save FileContents elsewhere. What you want is some form of projection like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449038/select-specific-columns-when-using-include-statement-with-entity-framework).

Comment: That looks promising, but the example the contained object isn't a collection.  So somehow I'd have to come up with a foreach() and build a new collection of anonymous objects?