# Entity Framework: How to select specific columns from a related entity

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a `PlayerContext` model that has many `BlueprintContext` models. Like so:

```
public class PlayerContext
    {
        public PlayerContext() { }

        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        ...
        public List<BlueprintContext> Blueprints { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

```
public class BlueprintContext
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<Coord3, Chonxels> BigData = new Dictionary<Coord3, Chonxels>() { };
        public Dictionary<BlueprintIngredient, int> recipe = new Dictionary<BlueprintIngredient, int>();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int CreatorId { get; set; }
        public PlayerContext Creator { get; set; }
    }
```

In `BlueprintContext` the `BigData` field can get really big. So when I load a `PlayerContext` I want the `Blueprints` but I only want the `id`, `recipe`, and `Name` fields (not the `BigData`).

Is there a way to load the `PlayerContext` and include the `BlueprintContext` fields I need without the `BigData` field?

Here is what I tried

```
        using (var db = new EfContext())
            {
                PlayerContext playerContext = db.Players
                    .Where(p => p.id == playerId)
                    ...
                    .Include(p => p.Blueprints.Select(b => new { b.id, b.recipe, b.Name}))
                    .AsNoTracking() // disables change tracking
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

and I get this Exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'p.Blueprints.AsQueryable().Select(b => new <>f__AnonymousType43`3(id = b.id, recipe = b.recipe, Name = b.Name))' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.
```

I'm using Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select specific columns when using include statement with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29449038/select-specific-columns-when-using-include-statement-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 1):

This is one reason to consider projecting your top level entity. For example if you want to display a summary detail of a player and their blueprints:

```
[Serializable]
public class PlayerSummaryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Any other fields the view actually needs.
    public IList<BlueprintSummaryViewModel> Blueprints { get; set; } = new List<BlueprintSummaryViewModel>();
}

public class BlueprintSummaryViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Recipe { get; set; }
}
```

Then project via `Select` or Automapper's `ProjectTo`:

```
using (var db = new EfContext())
{
    PlayerViewModel player = db.Players
        .Where(p => p.id == playerId)
        .Select(p => new PlayerSummaryViewModel
        {
            Id = p.Id,
            Name = p.Name,
            // ...
            Blueprints = p.Blueprints.Select(b => new BlueprintSummaryViewModel 
            {
                Id = b.Id,
                Name = b.Name,
                Recipe = b.Recipe
            }).ToList()
     }).Single();
}
```

With automapper since the properties are essentially 1 to 1 mappings with consistent naming, the mapping would essentially look like:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Player, PlayerSummaryViewModel>();
    cfg.CreateMap<Blueprint, BlueprintSummaryViewModel>();
};

using (var db = new EfContext())
{
    PlayerViewModel player = db.Players
        .Where(p => p.id == playerId)
        .ProjectTo<PlayerSummaryViewModel>(config)
        .Single();
}
```

Where config can be centralized for all view models or created on demand.

A reason why doing something like a selective include like you propose would be bad is that any method that accepts an entity should be able to expect that the entity passed is a complete representation of the domain state, or at least a complete-able representation. If you have a method that takes a Player entity, that method should not need the overhead to check whether that player does include Blueprints, or can include Blueprints, or might only get some pruned version of  Blueprints. View models or DTOs ensure that the type passed around is fit for purpose and it is clear what is expected.